# Diagram contents reference canvas to top

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I am making diagram (with help of the google of course). Simple nice working diagram, but I have little issues.

When I have referenced to Canvas.Top everything works nice, just Y axis is upside down .. so Y is getting from 0 to positive when moving mouse down and I like it that positive/higher value is at top and 0 is at bottom. When I reference Canvas to Bottom my points/nodes works fine only connectors/lines are still reference to "top".

How to add also the connectors/lines to Canvas.Bottom referencing.

Here is my XAML code:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>

        <CompositeCollection x:Key="DiagramCol">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.DiagramConnectors, Source={x:Reference diagramview}}"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.DiagramNodes, Source={x:Reference diagramview}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>

        <!--NODES-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DiagramNode}">

            <Canvas Name="dragTarget">

                <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_Drag" DragStarted="Thumb_DragStarted" DragCompleted="Thumb_DragCompleted">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Canvas Margin="-10,-10,10,10">
                                <Ellipse Height="17" Width="17" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Yellow"
                                         x:Name="Ellipse"/>
                                <TextBlock Canvas.Top="-20" Canvas.Left="-40" Width="100" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowNames, 
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                                                                Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

                                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="10"
                                           Text="{Binding X, StringFormat='{}X = {0}'}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Visible" x:Name="XText"/>

                                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="25"
                                           Text="{Binding Xmeaning}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Visible" x:Name="timeText"/>

                                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="40"
                                           Text="{Binding Y, StringFormat='{}Y = {0}'}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Visible" x:Name="YText"/>

                                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="55"
                                           Text="{Binding Ymeaning}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Visible" x:Name="luxText"/>

                            </Canvas>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowAllCoordinates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="XText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="YText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowCurrentCoordinates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="XText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="YText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                </Thumb>
            </Canvas>

        </DataTemplate>


        <!--CONNECTORS-->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DiagramConnector}">
            <Line Stroke="OrangeRed" StrokeThickness="3"
                  X1="{Binding Start.X}" Y1="{Binding Start.Y}"
                  X2="{Binding End.X}" Y2="{Binding End.Y}" x:Name="Line"/>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Start}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Line" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="column1" Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="23" />
            <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding GraphAddress}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbXlabel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Xlabellabel}" />
        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbYlabelLeft" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Ylabelleftlabel}">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbYlabelRight" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Ylabelrightlabel}">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>



        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"
                 PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
                 PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseDown"
                 PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewLeftMouseDown"
                 Margin="10,10,10,10"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 x:Name="LstBox">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" Opacity=".3">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <Border>
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile"
                                    Viewport="0,0,36,36" ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
                                    Viewbox="0,0,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            <Rectangle Stroke="Darkgray" StrokeThickness="0.5" Height="24" Width="24"
                                        StrokeDashArray="5 3"/>
                                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    </VisualBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </ScrollViewer>

                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>

            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DiagramCol"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>

            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="#01FFFFFF"
                            Height="{Binding AreaHeight}" Width="{Binding AreaWidth}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"/>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Effect">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" ShadowDepth="4" BlurRadius="10"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

So when I reference this line:

```
 <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
```

To:

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
```

then points/nodes works fine. Only the lines are the issue. In the code I like to add datatemplate of line to canvas bottom referencing, but how?

Please help. If any question please ask and if anything missing what you need, please say :)